# Anything wrong with this MySQL quert? takes 10 seconds+ to load

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have a search that is taking 10 seconds+ to execute!  Keep in mind it is also searching over 200,000 products in  the database.  I posted the explain and MySQL query here.

```
1  SIMPLE  p  ref  PRIMARY,products_status,prod_prodid_status,product...  products_status  1  const  9048  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE  v  ref  PRIMARY,vendors_id,vendors_vendorid  vendors_vendorid  4  rhinomar_rhinomartnew.p.vendors_id  1   
1  SIMPLE  s  ref  products_id  products_id  4  rhinomar_rhinomartnew.p.products_id  1   
1  SIMPLE  pd  ref  PRIMARY,products,prod_desc_prodid_prodname  prod_desc_prodid_prodname  4  rhinomar_rhinomartnew.p.products_id  1   
1  SIMPLE  p2c  ref  PRIMARY,ptc_catidx  PRIMARY  4  rhinomar_rhinomartnew.p.products_id  1  Using where; Using index
1  SIMPLE  c  eq_ref  PRIMARY  PRIMARY  4  rhinomar_rhinomartnew.p2c.categories_id  1  Using where
```

**MySQL Query:**

```
Select p.products_id, p.products_image, p.products_price, p.products_weight,
       p.products_unit_quantity,
       s.specials_new_products_price, s.status,
       pd.products_name, pd.products_img_alt
From products p 
Left Join vendors v On v.vendors_id = p.vendors_id 
Left Join specials s On s.products_id = p.products_id 
Left Join products_description pd On pd.products_id = p.products_id 
Left Join products_to_categories p2c On p2c.products_id = p.products_id 
Left Join categories c On c.categories_id = p2c.categories_id 
Where
(  pd.products_name Like '%apparel%'
   Or p2c.categories_id In (773, 132, 135, 136, 119, 122, 124, 125, 126, 1749, 1753,
                            1747, 123, 127, 130, 131, 178, 137, 140, 164, 165, 166,
                            167, 168, 169, 832, 2045 )
   Or p.products_id = 'apparel'
   Or p.products_model = 'apparel'
   Or Concat( v.vendors_prefix, '-' ) = 'apparel'
   Or Concat( v.vendors_prefix, '-', p.products_id ) = 'apparel'
) 
And p.products_status = '1' 
And c.categories_status = '1' 
Group By p.products_id 
Order By pd.products_name
```

Comment: What does `apparel` stand for in your case? Searching for `Concat( v.vendors_prefix, '-' ) = 'apparel'` won't return anything, since `apparel` does not end with a hyphen. And do you really need all `Left Joins` instead of `Joins`?

Comment: You mentioned querying over 200,000 products, but how many results do you get?  You're not missing a join somewhere?

Comment: Peter you were right!  I got rid of all the left joins except for one, so that seems to have sped it up quite a bit.  Also I indexed all the columns in the WHERE and AND clauses and the query appears to be running under 2.2 seconds consistently. :-)

Comment: Concat( v.vendors_prefix, '-' ) = 'apparel', right that doesn't return anything, but our guys need to be able to just type in "277-" for example and return all products that fit that particular vendor id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're only using `products_description` table in order to retrieve `products_name` and `products_img_alt`, Isn't it possible to have these two columns inside the `products` table?

Comment: this would take too much time by way of coding.  This is how osCommerce structured their database.

Answer (score 0):

As your `EXPLAIN` shows you, it's the `products_status` index that's being chosen, which I'm guessing is some kind of flag that shows whether the product is active?  There's probably not a lot of granularity there, so you're likely not getting a lot of help from that.

I don't know whether MySQL optimizes this already, but you should order items in your first `WHERE` predicate - the `(x OR y OR z)` by likelihood of match and by descending expense of evaluation.  Specifically, the `p2c.category_id IN (...)` should be at the beginning of the phrase, because that can use the index on `categories`.  The `CONCAT` should be last in the phrase, and the `LIKE` should be in the middle.

Normally a `UNION` is the best way to split up an `OR` phrase, but because some elements of your `OR` list are expensive functions, that might not be the best choice for you.

You should consider whether you can normalize your data somewhat, and read Peter Lang's comment for some good observations.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would say the reason it takes so long to load is because it has to create a temporary table on the disk. (hence the Using temporary; Using filesort;)

I recently ran into this same problem when I used a "WHERE id IN (1,2,3,etc)" clause. Could you remove that just to test if it prevents the filesort?

Comment: It's the `GROUP BY` that causes the filesort

Comment: In my case it wasn't. I had removed all ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses. But, I didn't notice the GROUP BY in the OP's query and you're right, it's more likely that that's causing it.